# Placing View left of another View in a RelativeLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I'm adding Views to a RelativeLayout. All of them are created and added programmaticaly, therefore solutions involving XML aren't possible for me.

The parent View is 300px wide. The added Views (A and B), are 15px wide each. First, I add View A.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpA
    = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
lpA.leftMargin = 150;
parent.addView(A, lpA);
```

This places A 150px from the left edge of parent. Works fine. But then I try to add View B.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpB
    = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
lpB.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, A.getId());
lpB.leftMargin = 0;
lpB.rightMargin = 0;
parent.addView(B, lpB)
```

Now I'm expecting B to be shown left of A, with no gap between them. Instead, B just vanishes. When setting lpB.rightMargin to an arbitrairy value of at least 1, B is shown on the left, as if aligned at parent's left edge.
Why is this happening? When changing the rule from LEFT_OF to RIGHT_OF, B is shown sticking to the right side of A, as expected.

Comment: What's the reason for `lpB.rightMargin = 0;`?

Comment: I would recommend building your layout in XML and viewing in the inspector, then once you have the correct parameters, build it programatically.

Comment: @codeMagic Funny story...I have to process non-Android XML files and the default value for the right margin is 0. Therefore it gets set, despite it's not necessary.